# Any global onClick function in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

When we develop the website in jQuery , we can do something like this.

```
$('button').click(function(){
     //Add Google Analytics 
})
```

But in react, we make different components with `styled-component`
I don't want to add the onClick function in each page and components.
Can I add something like jQuery click function?

Comment: I think you are missing the power of React. In react you create one single component called for example `MyButton` which does your custom action, and in all the pages in the HTML you simply add `<MyButton />` where you need it

Comment: You could attach global listener for example in parent component and in the componentDidMount but you need to check if your dom object exists (mounted) already and do your logics.

Comment: If you're using React, try to follow React's practices. React is an interface library, so you add onClick behaviour to the component that needs onClick behaviour, and then you simply use that component wherever it is needed in the UI. If you need a global event handler, you are _definitely_ doing React wrong, and are probably trying to implement "not React" in React (e.g. you're trying to force jQuery ideas into React code, which is a guaranteed recipe for bad code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common question for people who are new to React. You can create a React component which implements your function and use it across your project. This is a code sample with styled-components:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const StyledButton = styled.button`
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
`;

const yourFunction = e => console.log(e);

const Button = (props) => <StyledButton {...props} onClick={yourFunction}  />

export default Button;
```

Whenever you want to use it:

```
<Button>Click me!</Button>
```